# Adding time(hh:mm:ss) to a datetime field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to add the run_duration column(hh:mm:ss) to the run_datetime(datetime) column to calculate the endtime by using the following query:

```
SELECT checkdate, run_datetime, run_duration,
cast(run_datetime as datetime) + cast(run_duration as datetime) as readytime, 
cast(cast(run_datetime as datetime) + cast(run_duration as datetime) as datetime) as readytime_datetime
FROM table
```

The problem is that it is not adding up correctly for some records because it is summing above the 60 seconds:

[image]

Is there another way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL's built-in [addtime()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function instead of the `+` operator:

```
SELECT checkdate,
       run_datetime,
       run_duration,
       addtime(cast(run_datetime as datetime), cast(run_duration as time)) as readytime
FROM table
```

The `+` operator converts the datetimes to numbers and adds them up as such.

Comment: `cast(run_duration as time)` instead of `cast(run_duration as datetime)`?

Comment: @vkp fair point, updated the code. I'm not even sure to be hones if that's needed anyway.